# How do i use std.socket and std.socketstream? (D programming language 2.x)

Tags: sockets, networking, d

i was wondering how to use those phobos modules to use networking?

Or you can give a reference to how to use sockets (in a way similar or almost similar to D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std.socket.Socket is essentially a semi-thin wrapper around your operating system's native socket functions. For that reason, I recommend understanding the basics of socket programming in C first - there are plenty of examples for that - then, the std.socket API should be trivial.

For reference: http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_socket.html

Comment: well, but it could be better with a useful link of "understanding the basics of socket programming in C"

Answer (score 3):

from memory

```
auto MyStream = new SocketStream(new Socket(new TcpAddress("stakoverflow.com", 80)));
```